# JavaScript & Google Maps v3: capture result of tilesloaded() event?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with Javascript's asychronous nature, and Google Maps. I'm adding some markers to a map using the Google Maps V3 `tilesloaded` listener.

I don't know how to get hold of these markers so I can later do things with them, because tilesloaded fires asynchronously, and I'm a Javascript newbie!

Here's the code:

```
function show_place () {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var marker = addMarker(lat, lng);
    markers.push(marker);
    // When the map boundaries move, add new markers within the bounds.
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
      var bounds = map.getBounds();
      $.getJSON("/markers_within_bounds/", { [variables] }, function(json){
        for (i=0;i<json.length;i++) {
              var map_marker = addMarker(json[i].lat, json[i].lng);
                  markers.push(map_marker); //Try to add markers to the array. Fail.
        }
      });
    });
    return markers;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var markers = show_place(lat, lng);
    alert(markers.length);
    // Do things with the markers... if there is more than 1. 
});
```

The alert always shows 1, because `show_place` is returning BEFORE it loads all the markers. I can't get hold of the extra markers that have been added.

How can I get round this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should do that like this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: point,
    title: 'mytitle'
});
marker.setMap(myMap);
markersArray.push(marker);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may already have the markers in the variable, but when you request a length in

```
$(document).ready(function ...)
```

the length will always be one (1) because you inserted the marker, the inner function only fires after the tiles have been loaded all the while the show_place() has finished executing.  Your show_place() shouldn't return anything.  However, if you wanted to alert the user that you uploaded the data, you would put the code within the inner "Callback" function or call a declared function within the callback function block.

Answer (score 0):

1- I think you can make a public variable instead on returning a value from your function.
2- Please check inside the firebug console to see is there any problem.
3- instead of using tilesloaded, you can use idle or bounds_changed(better to avoid since the google call this event many times)

```
var markerList = [];
function (data){//AJAX CALLBACK FUNCTION
  //EMPTY THE LIST & CLEAR THE MARKER FROM MAP
  for (var i = 0; i < markerList.length; i++) {
    markerList[i].setMap();
  };
  markerList.length = 0;
  markerList[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].geo_latitude, data[i].geo_longitude),
    title: data[i].fn
  });
};
```